# Laravel Mail Later sends email multiple times

Tags: laravel, queue

I'm using this approach to prevent queue emails reaching smtp limit, but sometimes emails get sent twice or even more, any ideas on why this might be happening?

```
            $when = now();
            foreach($users as $user){
                $when->addSeconds(2);
                Mail::to($user->email)
                ->later($when, new RememberEmail($when));
            }
```

Comment: Are you 100% certain that your $users collection doesn't contain duplicates?

Comment: Yes, actually I tried sending all emails to the same address and still happens the same.

Answer (score 0):

In your config/mail have you got `To` defined ? if so try removing this ?

Answer (score 0):

After some time searching for an answer I found this one my problem was solved.

[Laravel multiple workers running job twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51425360/laravel-multiple-workers-running-job-twice/51933021#51933021)